# Two Dimensional Array as Object Name?

Tags: php, arrays

Dynamically created textbox would have names in array format.

```
<input type="textbox" id="textbox[]" name="textbox[]">
```

If updating dynamically created check box would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox[]" name="chkbox[]">

$checkbox = $_POST['chkbox'];
$id = "('" . implode( "','", $checkbox ) . "');" ;
$sql = "UPDATE [table] SET [col] = [value] WHERE id IN " . $id . ";
```

How could I do the same idea with text boxes?

Comment: It's probably just me, but I don't understand the question.

Comment: Doesn't the `I need` part emphasize what I meant sir? or do I need to re-phrase my sentence if its misleading?

Comment: Maybe if you could [add](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34508013/edit) the output of `var_export($_POST);` - you're saving/updating data, so I assume you use POST to transmit the data) - and comment on that (concrete) data, it might help.

Comment: How can I know which ID to update then for each value?

Comment: Updated the question, Hope it gives more clearer view to what I needed help with.

Comment: Oh, an sql UPDATE. You probably want to transmit IDs of the records you want to update and the respective text data, right? Is the html form code already in place or are you looking or just any viable approach? By "Dynamically created textbox" you mean, it's done via javascript on the client side ...or by php on the server side?

Comment: Yes, it is done on php server side

Comment: Ok, I gave it a try. If you have compound data, i.e. something that would make sens to group together in one `<fieldset class="editgroup">` in my example html/javascript`, let me know (and elaborate) - it might be worth to structure the names a bit differently then. The goal (in my book) should be to be able to iterate one compund group/record/row easily via a simple foreach-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an UPDATE statement in your question I assume you're sending existing records from your database (having some kind of id) to the client first.
In that case you can put that id in the field name, e.g.

```
<input type="text" name="text[47] value="..." />
<input type="text" name="text[74] value="..." />
<input type="text" name="text[39] value="..." />
```

and then on the server side iterate the data like

```
foreach( $_POST['text'] as $id=>$value ) {
  // your database action here, preferably a prepared statement
}
```

something to play with:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            span.editbtn { cursor: pointer; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="test.php">
            <!-- something like this your script would produce from the SELECT query -->
            <fieldset class="editgroup"><input type="text"  name="post[47]" value="value for id 47" disabled /></fieldset>
            <fieldset class="editgroup"><input type="text"  name="post[74]" value="value for id 74" disabled /></fieldset>
            <fieldset class="editgroup"><input type="text"  name="post[89]" value="value for id 89" disabled /></fieldset>
            <fieldset class="editgroup"><input type="text"  name="post[31]" value="value for id 31" disabled /></fieldset>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <div id="foo">.</div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('fieldset.editgroup').each(function() {
                    $(this).append('<span class="editbtn">&#x270e;</span>');
                });
                $('fieldset.editgroup').on('click', '.editbtn', function() {
                    $(this).siblings('input').prop('disabled', false);
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

check the result in test.php via `<pre><?php var_export($_POST); ?></pre>`

Comment: Thank you! The foreach() is enough.